# How to make count increment with Websocket api using React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

I have notification icon button which has count so i want the count to be incremented whenever new data is fetched using Websocket api,how can i achieve that,and how make this websocket as component which will recieve prop

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Websocket = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let ws = new Websocket("wss://example.com");
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log("connection open");
     
    };
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      setCount(e.data);
    };
  });
};

export default Websocket;
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i get you right, i'm guessing you're trying to increment count from lets say 0 to the value return from the socket? If so then always remember that the setter function of a hook can take a callback with the current state as its parameter, hence:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Websocket = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let ws = new Websocket("wss://example.com");
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log("connection open");
     
    };
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
      setCount(state => state + e.data);
    };
  });
};

export default Websocket;
```

This should work if that's what you mean in your question.

Comment: ok,but where are we opening the connection and i want to make this as Dynamic component which we can pass props like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-websocket